# Unable to get record from database with Between condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

Dates are Svaing in my datatbase with this format.

```
04 Feb 2016
04 Mar 2016
04 Mar 2016
04 Mar 2016
04 Mar 2016
```

And I am using

```
 select CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),Convert(datetime,CREATEDATE),106)
 from job
 where CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),Convert(datetime,CREATEDATE),106) 
 between     Convert(VARCHAR(20),Convert(datetime,getdate())-25,106)
         AND CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),Convert(datetime,GETDATE()),106)
```

SQL statement for get result from database. But I am unable to get any record.

Comment: Why do you store date/timestamps in a VarChar? And why convert it to a datetime and then back to a VarChar?

Answer (score 0):

**STOP** storing and parsing `dates` as `VARCHAR`. Store Dates in `DATETIME` or `DATE` datatype instead of `Varchar` which will help you to avoid all these conversion's

Now coming back to the problem, You are trying to compare `Varchar` between `Varchar1` and `Varchar2` which not same as `Date` between `Date1` and `Date2`.

Convert the `CREATEDATE` to `datetime` and compare with dates in `Between` clause

```
;WITH job
     AS (SELECT *
         FROM   (VALUES (Cast('04 Feb 2016' AS VARCHAR(50))),
                        (Cast('04 Mar 2016' AS VARCHAR(50))),
                        (Cast('04 Mar 2016' AS VARCHAR(50))),
                        (Cast('04 Mar 2016' AS VARCHAR(50))),
                        (Cast('04 Mar 2016' AS VARCHAR(50)))) cs (CREATEDATE))
SELECT CREATEDATE
FROM   job
WHERE  CONVERT(DATETIME, CREATEDATE) BETWEEN Getdate() - 25 AND Getdate()
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you do reverse convert back to varchar? It works fine without:

```
declare @job table (CREATEDATE varchar(50));
insert into @job values
('04 Feb 2016'),
('04 Mar 2016'),
('04 Mar 2016'),
('04 Mar 2016'),
('04 Mar 2016');

select Convert(datetime,CREATEDATE,106)
 from @job t
 where Convert(datetime,CREATEDATE,106) 
 between     Convert(datetime,getdate()-25,106)
         AND Convert(datetime,getdate(),106)
;
```